# Yammer API - unseen messages and notifications

Tags: sharepoint, integration, yammer

I am developing an integration from SharePoint to yammer enterprise. 
The integration will be two images, the envelope and the bell icon from yammer. 
Along those should the the correct numbers. Through all the API's given at 
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ I have only managed to find the amount of notifications at the networks/current.json. 
Under many different api's are numbers with names such as unseen messages, but they do not referer to this specific number. It should be easy to find and I am sure that somebody out there is smart enough to know this.

If Anybody knows which api I should call, then I it would be much appreciated if they share it =)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the following code and you will get unseen notification and unseen message count.

```
           yam.platform.request({
                url: "networks/current.json",
                method: "GET",
                data: {},
                success: function (networks) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < networks.length; i++) {
                        if (networks[i].permalink === "permalink_name") {
                            var msgCount = networks[i].unseen_message_count;
                            var notificationCount = networks[i].unseen_notification_count;
                        }
                    }

                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("There was an error with the request.");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hey Bayzid,
Thank you for the response =)
I have tried the unseen message count, however it does not seem to be aligned with the number shown above the envelope.
Actually i have never seen the unseen meesage count here as anything else than -1. 
Maybe I am using it wrong, but I do not believe so, as the yammer developer page with the examples show the same thing. 
Best wishes Povl

Comment: Hej Polv, I have also noticed that unseen message count are -1 if there is no unseen message in the inbox but i believe it will show the right number if there is any :)

Comment: Hey Again Bayzid =) I have tried several different ways to get numbers up on the envelope now. None of these changes the -1 from the networks/current.json. Have you tried it? Does it work for you?